# I have created a function in C but it does not seem to make any changes to the variable I want to modify

Tags: c, embedded

this is my first post on this page, I just learned the C language a few days ago.

I have a problem with this C code, the idea is that the function "create_test_buffer" modifies the variable "test_ptr" adding a value of 100 in each position, but when I print "test_ptr" again after calling the function, nothing seems to have changed.

The checksum doesn't seem to be modified either, it is supposed that if you add a value of 100 in each position and in total the array has 512 positions you should get 512*100=51200, but instead it is showing 6400.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TEST_BUFFER_LEN             512
#define NETWORK_SCAN_LIST_SIZE      8

typedef struct {
    char ssid[33];
} wifi_ap_record_t;

wifi_ap_record_t ap_info_struct[NETWORK_SCAN_LIST_SIZE] =
{
    {.ssid="SSID_3"},
    {.ssid="SSID_1"},
    {.ssid="SSID_1"},
    {.ssid="SSID_1"},
    {.ssid="SSID_1"},
    {.ssid="SSID_2"},
    {.ssid="SSID_1"},
    {.ssid="SSID_1"},
};

uint16_t test_ptr[TEST_BUFFER_LEN];
uint16_t test_len = 0;

static void create_test_buffer(uint16_t *, uint16_t *);
static uint16_t calculate_checksum(uint16_t *, uint16_t);

int main()
{
    printf("test_ptr before: %x\n", test_ptr);
    printf("len before: %x\r\n", test_len);
    create_test_buffer(test_ptr, &test_len);
    printf("test_ptr after: %x\n", test_ptr);
    printf("len after: %x\r\n", test_len);
    uint16_t checksum = calculate_checksum(test_ptr, TEST_BUFFER_LEN);
    printf("Checksum: %x\r\n", checksum);

    return 0;
}

static void create_test_buffer(uint16_t *buff_ptr, uint16_t *len)
{
#define TEST_BUFFER_LEN 512
    static uint16_t test_buffer[TEST_BUFFER_LEN];
    for (uint16_t idx = 0 ; idx < TEST_BUFFER_LEN; ++idx) {
        test_buffer[idx] = 0x64;
    }
    memcpy(buff_ptr, test_buffer, TEST_BUFFER_LEN);
    // buff_ptr = test_buffer;
    len = TEST_BUFFER_LEN;
}

static uint16_t calculate_checksum(uint16_t *data, uint16_t len)
{
    uint16_t idx = 0;
    uint16_t checksum = 0;
    while (idx < len) {
        checksum += data[idx];
        idx++;
    }
    return checksum;
}
```

as for the functions I have tried to change the way the modification of the parameters is done, first I tried with "len = TEST_BUFFER_LEN;" and then with "memcpy(buff_ptr, test_buffer, TEST_BUFFER_LEN);" being this last one the one that at least allows me to see a change in the checksum.

Comment: Why C is tagged C++?

Comment: *len = whatever - note the asterisk - close as typo?

Comment: `len = TEST_BUFFER_LEN;` Ignoring compiler warnings (at the beginning of studying!) is a bad habit.

Comment: `memcpy(buff_ptr, test_buffer, TEST_BUFFER_LEN);` will copy 512 `bytes`, not 512 `uint16-t`'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to dereference the pointer to "len".

```
*len = TEST_BUFFER_LEN;
```

This means "Write to the variable that len *points to*". If you forget the `*`, you overwrite the pointer, and not the thing the pointer points to.

You've also got at least one more mistake in the code - `memcpy` takes the length in bytes, not 16-bit words, so you have to multiply the length with the size of each element before passing that to memcpy.

```
memcpy(buff_ptr, test_buffer, TEST_BUFFER_LEN * sizeof(uint16_t));
```

Your compiler likely warned you about both of these. You should take compiler warnings seriously, and ideally, enable all of them (i.e. `-Wall -Wextra` on GCC/Clang)